# Buffer length setting for Video.JS Flash plugin?

Tags: nginx, video-streaming, rtmp, video.js

I'm streaming live rtmp video from nginx to a Video.JS Flash player and see the video is consistently choppy.  I noticed its delay is about 1 second from reality and would like to increase the buffer length on the Video.JS player side to avoid this choppiness.  Something like the JWPlayer 'bufferlength' feature.

Any way to do this on Video.JS?

My Video.JS is added via Flash plugin like this:

```
<script src="bower_components/videojs/dist/video-js/video.js"></script>
```

Comment: Looks like you forgot to add how VideoJS is added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 1s buffer appears to be [hardcoded](https://github.com/videojs/video-js-swf/blob/6d262f5c9b6f1d919220201f0c1f0bc113a2271a/src/com/videojs/providers/RTMPVideoProvider.as#L421), so there's not currently going to be any top-level player options you can set to change that. While not ideal, you can always modify and build your own swf. Also you can submit an issue on the [swf repo](https://github.com/videojs/video-js-swf/) requesting that be exposed.